# Hover , Focus and Blur conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to apply 4 effects on an element:

1. On hovering over the element.
2. On hovering away from the element.
3. On focusing on the element.
4. On blur.

But there is a conflict happens , When I focus on the element the hover in and out runs , and when I click outside the element the effect that should happens on blur doesn't happen , I think it's because of the hover out.

```js
var el = $('input');

el.focus(function() {
  el.css('border', '1px solid green');
});

el.hover(function() {
  el.css('border', '1px solid green');
}, function() {
  el.css('border', '1px solid grey');
});

el.blur(function() {
  if (el.val == '') {
    el.css('border', '1px solid red');
  } else {
    el.css('border', '1px solid grey');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

On hovering in the border color turns green , on hovering out it turns grey.
But on focusing on the input the color is grey not green, and in blur it's grey too not red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to the logic in your `if` condition. `el.val` returns the reference of the function, which will never equate to an empty string. You need to use `el.val()` instead to get the actual value of the control:

```js
var el = $('input');

el.focus(function() {
  el.css('border', '1px solid green');
});

el.hover(function() {
  el.css('border', '1px solid green');
}, function() {
  el.css('border', '1px solid grey');
});

el.blur(function() {
  if (el.val() == '') {
    el.css('border', '1px solid red');
  } else {
    el.css('border', '1px solid grey');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

That being said I would suggest combining CSS rules with this where possible, and definitely using classes over joining the styling rules with the JS code so tightly. Something like this:

```js
var el = $('input');
el.blur(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('empty', $(this).val().trim() === '');
});
```

```css
input {
  outline: 0;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
input:hover,
input:focus {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

input.empty {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

Comment: Thanks , The blur problem is resolved but there is still a conflict between hover out and focus

Comment: It goes green for me. I edited the answer to remov the `outline` and make the border thicker so it's easier to see.

Comment: That's great , But what if I want to show a message if the value is empty ? `el.after('<div class="inputError" style="display:block">This Field Can\'t Be Empty</div>');`

Comment: That would work, you'd just need to use the original `if` statement you had. I'd also suggest checking to see if that error already exists, otherwise you could end up with lots of them repeated.

Comment: Yes you are right I did both the checks and everything goes well now , Thanks so much